# Django Rest Framework сериализация

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, сериализация

Пишу API на DjangoRest, необходимо вместо id цветов, вывести их название. Не могу разобраться как в этот код приткнуть RelatedField

## models.py

```
class Colors(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField('Цвет', max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Название", max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    size = models.DecimalField("Размер", max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    color = models.ManyToManyField(Colors, max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField("Цена", max_length=6)
    description = models.CharField("Описание", max_length=200)
    gender = models.ForeignKey('Gender', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantity = models.IntegerField("Кол-во на складе", max_length=10)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', verbose_name="Фото", blank=True)
    seen = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Просмотрено", default=False, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## serializers.py

```
class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'pk', 'name', 'category', 'size', 'color', 'price', 'description', 'gender', 'quantity', 'image', 'seen')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(ProductsSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        rep['category'] = instance.category.name
        rep['gender'] = instance.gender.gender
        return rep
```

## Текущий выввод

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "name": "Подкрадули скороходы",
        "category": "Подкрадули",
        "size": "32.50",
        "color": [
            3, ## Белый ##
            4  ## Чёрный ##
        ],
        "price": 1000,
        "description": "XXX",
        "gender": "Мужской",
        "quantity": 100,
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/podkraduli-mem.jpg",
        "seen": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Так как в классе был dunder метод str, помогло следующее решение.

```
class ProductsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    color = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True) ##решение
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'pk', 'name', 'category', 'size', 'color', 'price', 'description', 'gender', 'quantity', 'image', 'seen')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(ProductsSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        rep['category'] = instance.category.name
        rep['gender'] = instance.gender.gender
        return rep
```